# File.Delete() not working in run mode but only works in debug mode

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, file-io

I am having a weird problem.
I save uploaded file to database and then try to delete the uploaded file
from upload folder.

This works fine in debug mode but in run mode, the file remains undeleted.

Anyone faced this issue?

This is .NET 4

Code snippet below:

```
private string SaveFiles(string rootFolder)
{
  var uploadedPhotos = GetAllFilesUploaded();
foreach (var file in uploadedFiles)
{
                string path= Path.Combine(rootFolder, "userfile", file.FileName);

                FileService.SaveUploadedFile(fileName, GetBytesFromLocalFile(path));

                File.Delete(path); <-- this only works in debug mode!!

                }
    }

    public static byte[] GetBytesFromLocalFile(string filePath)
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                    return bytes;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO since it is working in Debug Mode then this is no coding problem. Problem lies with your path that is being provided for File.Delete(path). since acc to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

```
If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.
```

Check path in Release mode. May be its something to do with Release and Debug Folder in bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Nikhil's answer, I'd suggest to put a `MessageBox` with the `path` in release mode and manually check if the path is right.

NOTE: Don't forget to remove the `MessageBox` after.