# How to delete files in AppData/Temp after file upload with .NET WebAPI 2? File in use error

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload files to S3 after a user uploads a file to my API. I obviously don't want them to live on MY server, in fact I'd prefer they never exist on the server at all. My problem is that the files appear to remain in use for the lifetime of server app! Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var provider = GetMultipartProvider();
    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var originalFileName = GetDeserializedFileName(result.FileData.First());
    var fi = new FileInfo(result.FileData.First().LocalFileName);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(originalFileName).ToLower();

    var amazonKey = S3Helper.Upload(fi.FullName, extension);

    // DELETE THE FILE HERE (BodyPart_2f33be26-09a2-4ae3-8b89-4158b99fe32d)
    File.Delete(fi.FullName); // This doesn't work, file in use error...

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Img{ 
        Extension = extension,
        S3Key = amazonKey.Key,
        OriginalFilename = originalFileName
    });
}
```

**How, when or where do I delete these files? OR is there a way to keep the files from being written to my server's disk in the first place?**

Comment: try disposing of your result, and be sure to handle IOExceptions

Comment: I've not used these bits before, but since you reference `filedata` you seem to be using the FileStreamProvider. using the `memoryStreamProvider` would mean the files are only stored in memory & not written to disk. Not sure if your `S3helper` supports that though

Comment: FileInfo creates a lock on the file even if you dont actually do anything with it. I'd suggest copy the filepath to a string variable and use that instead.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the issue when I came back around and read this today.  

Anyone know if there is a way around having these files put on the servers hard drive in the first place?

Comment: If the files are small (1MB or less) and the traffic on your site is medium - low you could store the file in a memory buffer (either byte[] or MemoryStream ), I'm not familiar with S3 uploads, maybe it has an option to upload a stream, then you can grab the stream as it comes from the upload and push it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22546747/2164198) shows that this approach should work in general. The only visible differences are:

1. You're using FileInfo. So why don't you use [FileInfo's Delete method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete(v=vs.100).aspx)?
2. You're using `S3Helper.Upload(fi.FullName, extension)`. Try to comment this line out to determine if it locks the file.

Comment: The S3Helper was locking the file.  Duh.  I also didn't know FileInfo had Delete on it.  How handy...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but s3helper.upload might be uploading on background thread. Try this

```
While(true){
  try {
     // delete file
     break;
  } catch () {
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
 }
```

Just looked at s3 docs and yes it uses not just a background thread but multiple!

> Uploads the specified file. The object key is derived from the file's name. Multiple threads are used to read the file and perform multiple uploads in parallel. For large uploads, the file will be divided and uploaded in parts using Amazon S3's multipart API. The parts will be reassembled as one object in Amazon S3.

Comment: what if it fails constantly? your code would produce an infinite loop!